# regex pattern for phone number

Tags: regex

I need a pettern for phone number like +7(9xx)-xxx-xx-xx,
I tried `^(\+7)[()0-9-]{16}$/gmi` https://regex101.com/r/oJ6rE0/1 but I doesn't work and it is not full pattern. How to make it work?

Comment: `^\+7[()0-9-]{15}$` will work for your example but you need to clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid a bit of garbage  that could allow `^\+7[()0-9-]{15}$` (it accepts `+7---------------` as a valid number) I suggest you to use:

```
^\+7\(9\d{2}\)-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
```

Note that you don't need `i` flag since you're not dealing with case sensitive chars.